# What determines barter rates for goons, Rez and data?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

Civilian stations trade one type of resource (Goons for Rez, Rez for goons, data for goons) for another depending on the system's type (Colony, Mining, Science). The exchange rate, however, can vary drastically from system to system. What factors influence these rates?

Comment: It's been a while since I played, but I seem to recall your standing with them being the major factor. The system level might also factor in.

Answer (score 1):

The barter rates are affected by your local faction reputation which you can confirm easily yourself by checking prices before and after a bribe and by the perks from your currently used specialists.

The Specialist perks which affect trading are:

- Diplomat: Warpgate bribe discount
- Slaver: Goon trade discount
- Mediator: Relation improve discount
- Negotiator: Blue print discount

Source: [Specialist Skill tables](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Specialist_Skill_Table)

Comment: In my experience prices are not affected by your relationship with the seller's faction.